# Records appear to be locked between sequential database operations (Spring Data, Hibernate)

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data

I'm experiencing what seems to be a record lock between sequential (not concurrent) database operations, which I can't explain.

**Situation**

Method `saveRegistrationToken` is called from a REST controller. I test the calls to the method via Postman (HTTP client); the method is not called anywhere else, this is the only operation executed.

The method execution is supposed to behave as follows:

- Take a String (registration token) and a user ID (also a string) as input
- It should first update a USERS table, setting the value of the REGISTRATION_TOKEN column to null for every row where the column has the same value as the input registration token
- It should then update the USERS table for the row with the specified user ID, setting the value of the REGISTRATION_TOKEN column to the input registration token.

**Problem**

- Every first execution of the method will behave as expected: sets the value of the DB column REGISTRATION_TOKEN (table USER) to null wherever it is the specified value, and then sets the registration token to the input value for the row with the input user ID. As such, the value of the registration token for the row in question is the input value at the end of the execution of the method.
- Every second execution will correctly do the first step ("void" the registration token wherever it exists) but does not update the value for the row with the specified user ID. As such, the value of the registration token for the row in question is null at the end of the execution of the method.

*DefaultUserService.java*

```
@Override
public void saveRegistrationToken(String userId, String registrationToken) {
    usersRepository.voidRegistrationToken(registrationToken);
    User u = usersRepository.findById(userId).get();
    u.setRegistrationToken(registrationToken);
    usersRepository.save(u);
}
```

*UsersRepository.java*

```
@Repository
public interface UsersRepository extends JpaRepository<User, String> {

    @Modifying
    @Transactional
    @Query(value = "UPDATE USERS " +
        "SET registration_token = null " +
        "WHERE registration_token = :registration_token",
        nativeQuery = true)
    void voidRegistrationToken(@Param("registration_token") String registrationToken);
}
```

*User.java*

```
@Entity(name = "users")
@AllArgsConstructor //lombok
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class User {
    @Id
    private String id;
    private String registrationToken;
    private String email;
}
```

**What I've tried**

- I initially thought it would be a flush problem: that once the registration token had been set to null everywhere, the transaction would not be flushed until after the registration token had been set again for the user ID, leading to conflicting behaviour between both DB operations. I disproved that explicitly calling `usersRepository.flush();` after the first operation, and observing the same behaviour.
- I tried different propagation and isolation levels on the repository operation:     `@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.SUPPORTS, isolation = Isolation.READ_UNCOMMITTED)`, which didn't help.
- I tried explicitly setting the flush mode on the repository operation: `@QueryHints(value = { @QueryHint(name = org.hibernate.annotations.QueryHints.FLUSH_MODE, value = "ALWAYS") })` , which didn't change anything.
- It now seems to me that the first operation "locks" the updated record, which prevents the second operation from updating it, but I don't understand how.
- Explicitly specifying auto-commit true: `spring.datasource.auto-commit=true`

Dependencies: `compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")` effectively version 2.1.1.RELEASE

Any ideas, explanations, links to docs would be very much appreciated - I've tried everything I can think of.

Many thanks, Chris

**UPDATE:**

Another reason I think it's some kind of flush problem.

I updated this method as follows:

```
@Override
public void saveRegistrationToken(String userId, String registrationToken) {
    usersRepository.voidRegistrationToken(registrationToken);

    String check = usersRepository.findById(userId).get().getRegistrationToken();

    /* breakpoint on the following line */
    User u = usersRepository.findById(userId).get();
    u.setRegistrationToken(registrationToken);
    usersRepository.save(u);
}
```

When stopping at the breakpoint where indicated:

- Every first ("normal") execution, the value of the `check` variable is `null`
- Every second execution, its value is the same as the input registration token

Comment: Are you using a 2nd level cache? It could be that hibernate fails to evict the updated entries because you're using a native query to perform the update

Comment: Nothing more than is included in out-of-the-box spring data

Comment: Is `saveRegistrationToken` using `@Transactional`?

Comment: Nope! The annotation is on the repository method: voidRegistrationToken

Comment: @ChrisNeve Normally I do not use `clear` because of the possible implications in the `PersistenceContext`, but have you tried to clear the `PersistenceContext` after the initial operation is performed? I mean, please, can you modify the declaration of the modifying annotation in the `saveRegistrationToken`method to `@Modifying(clearAutomatically = true)`? Please, see the [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/Modifying.html#clearAutomatically--).

Comment: @jccampanero yep, that worked. A bit gutted I didn't find that before. Can you write it as an answer with an explanation on what it does exactly? The docs are a bit scarce. I'll accept your answer

Comment: That is nice Chris, I am happy to hear that it worked. Yes, of course.

Comment: also an explanation on what the pros/cons can be (what are the possible implications in the PersistenceContext, and why should it be avoided?)

Comment: Yes, of course. Chis, please, can you try to annotate the `saveRegistrationToken` as `@Transactional` and see if it works?

Comment: Already tried as the code shows :) didn't help, regardless of the different propagation and isolation combinations I tried

Comment: Yes, I see. But, did you annotated the service or the repository? I mean, did you also try to annotate the service method?

Comment: Adding the @Transactional method on the service call (without the clearAutomatically in the @Modifying) gave the same results as described in the post - didn't help

Comment: Thank you for trying Chris. It is a strange problem indeed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I always prefer to mark the service method as `@Transactional` as a whole, reviewing your code, I think you defined the appropriate transaction demarcation in your methods, by explicitly define the `@Transactional` annotation in `voidRegistrationToken`, and by using the methods provided by `JpaRepository`, implicitly annotated in such a way.

In any case, as you indicated, as a result of performing the different operations over the `User` who will be assigned the registration token, you are obtaining inconsistent values.

It is a clear indication that the information of the affected `User` entity maintained by the `EntityManager` in the persistence context is being polluted somewhere across the different methods invocation.

I honestly cannot give you the exact reason about this behavior.

It may have to do with the moment in which the changes are flushed to the database, to entirely discretion of the `EntityManager`, but you already tried to flush the different changes manually and your transactions seems appropriate and, as a consequence, it will probably not be the cause of the problem.

Maybe it have to do with a second level cache as @Guillaume suggested, maybe with the way the `@Modifying` operation is implemented by Spring Data.

One think you can try is to instruct your `@Modifying` annotation to [clear](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#clear--) the persistence context once the operation is completed:

```java
@Modifying(clearAutomatically = true)
```

This will provide you a clean state to perform the registration token update.

Please, see the relevant [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/Modifying.html#clearAutomatically--).

Please, be aware that the possible implications of the use of this solution.

The use of `flush` and `clear` in `EntityManager` is an anti-pattern, something that should be avoided if you can by using the appropriate transaction demarcations and component architecture.

The call of `clear` leads to all objects being decoupled from the `EntityManager`. Be aware that, depending of the use case, even modified object data will not be saved to the database - this is the main difference with `flush` that always will preserve the modifications performed to the entities managed in the persistence context before detach them.

In any case, due to the way your transactions are defined, probably in your use case it will work properly.